# Lisp function to return a number double and then the same number doubled plus one

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am totally new to lisp and have no idea how I'll create this function. 
This is the pseudo code I created to help me solve it

```
Binary tree children
; This function returns the children of binary tree node
; e.g., 3 -> (6,7)
; e.g., 11 -> (22,23) 
(defun tree-node(x))
```

The function is intended to take in a number, double it, and then double it and add 1. Please help.

Comment: You are expected to put some effort into it. Stackoverflow isn't really the place to write code for you.

Comment: I understand but i am a total novice in lisp

Comment: @NnachetaNnyagu SO is probably not for you if you have so littlw knowledge of the language that you would be incapable of understanding the answer. Perhaps you should [read a book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)

Answer (score 2):

To double a number (which is stored in a variable named `n` here): `(* 2 n)`.

To add one: `(1+ n)`.  Note that `1+` is the *name* of a function.  It is the same as `(+ n 1)`.

Now, let's say that you have some scope (e. g. a function body) where you have a variable named `n`.  You now create a new variable `d` using `let`:

```
(let ((d (* n 2)))
  …)
```

This new variable is in scope for the body of the `let` (indicated by `…` above).

Now we create another variable `d1`, which is one more.  We need to use `let*` now, so that the scope of `d` is not just the body, but also the binding forms of the `let*`:

```
(let* ((d (* n 2))
       (d1 (+ d 1)))
  …)
```

The function should maybe be called `child-indices`:

```
(defun child-indices (n)
  (let* ((d (* n 2))
         (d1 (+ d 1)))
    …))
```

The bodies of many forms like `defun` and `let` are so-called *implicit progns*, which means that these forms return the value of the last expression in their body.  So, whatever forms we put into the place marked `…` above, the value (or values, but let's keep that aside for now) of the last is the return value of the function.

There are several ways to do a “return this and then that”, but we'll use a list for now:

```
(defun child-indices (n)
  (let* ((d (* n 2))
         (d1 (+ d 1)))
    (list d d1)))
```